# PeekNamedPipe cannot give correct number of bytes available when given a Handle from the server, only works when the Handle come from the client

Tags: c++, windows, named-pipes

The PeekNamedPipe function documentation says that the Handle argument can come from the server side (CreateNamedPipe) or the client side(CreateFile).

> hNamedPipe [in] A handle to the pipe. This parameter can be a handle
>   to a named pipe instance, as returned by the CreateNamedPipe or
>   CreateFile function, or it can be a handle to the read end of an
>   anonymous pipe, as returned by the CreatePipe function. The handle
>   must have GENERIC_READ access to the pipe.

When I give the function an Handle coming from CreateNamedPipe, I always get 0 as number of bytes available no matter what the pipe actually contains.

The following code works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    wcout << "Creating an instance of a named pipe..." << endl;

    // Create a pipe to send data
    HANDLE pS = CreateNamedPipe(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\my_pipe", PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, 0, 1, 100, 100, 0, NULL);

    // Open the named pipe
    HANDLE pC = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\my_pipe", GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (pC == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        wcout << "Failed to connect to pipe." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    wcout << "Test PeekNamedPipe #1." << endl;
    DWORD PipeByteNum = 0;
    BOOL res = PeekNamedPipe(pC, NULL, 0, NULL, &PipeByteNum, NULL);
    if(!res)
    {
          wcout << "PeekNamedPipe() - failed." << endl;
          return 1;
    }
    wcout << " - Number of bytes in pipe: " << PipeByteNum << endl << endl;

    wcout << "Sending data to pipe..." << endl;

   const wchar_t *data = L"Hello Pipe World";
   DWORD numBytesWritten = 0;
   BOOL result = WriteFile(pS, data, wcslen(data) * sizeof(wchar_t), &numBytesWritten, NULL);

    if (result)
      wcout << "Number of bytes sent: " << numBytesWritten << endl;
    else
    {
      wcout << "Failed to send data." << endl;
      return 1;
    }

    wcout << "Test PeekNamedPipe #2." << endl;
    PipeByteNum = 0;
    res = PeekNamedPipe(pC, NULL, 0, NULL, &PipeByteNum, NULL);
    if(!res)
    {
          wcout << "PeekNamedPipe() - failed." << endl;
          return 1;
    }
    wcout << " - Number of bytes in pipe: " << PipeByteNum << endl << endl;

    wcout << "Reading data from pipe..." << endl;

    // The read operation will block until there is data to read
    wchar_t buffer[128];
    DWORD numBytesRead = 0;
    result = ReadFile(pC, buffer, 5 * sizeof(wchar_t), &numBytesRead, NULL);

    if (result)
    {
      buffer[numBytesRead / sizeof(wchar_t)] = '\0'; // null terminate the string
      wcout << "Number of bytes read: " << numBytesRead << endl;
      wcout << "Message: " << buffer << endl;
    }
    else
    {
      wcout << "Failed to read data from the pipe." << endl;
      return 1;
    }

    wcout << "Test PeekNamedPipe #3." << endl;
    PipeByteNum = 0;
    res = PeekNamedPipe(pC, NULL, 0, NULL, &PipeByteNum, NULL);
    if(!res)
    {
          wcout << "PeekNamedPipe() - failed." << endl;
          return 1;
    }
    wcout << " - Number of bytes in pipe: " << PipeByteNum << endl << endl;

    // Close client.
    CloseHandle(pC);
    wcout << "Done with client." << endl;

    // Close the pipe.
    CloseHandle(pS);
    wcout << "Done with server." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The outpout is :

```
Creating an instance of a named pipe...
Test PeekNamedPipe #1.
 - Number of bytes in pipe: 0

Sending data to pipe...
Number of bytes sent: 32
Test PeekNamedPipe #2.
 - Number of bytes in pipe: 32

Reading data from pipe...
Number of bytes read: 10
Message: Hello
Test PeekNamedPipe #3.
 - Number of bytes in pipe: 22

Done with client.
Done with server.
```

Now, if I give pS (server handle) to PeekNamedPipe instead of pC (client handle), the number of number of bytes available is always 0.

The outpout becomes:

```
Creating an instance of a named pipe...
Test PeekNamedPipe #1.
 - Number of bytes in pipe: 0

Sending data to pipe...
Number of bytes sent: 32
Test PeekNamedPipe #2.
 - Number of bytes in pipe: 0

Reading data from pipe...
Number of bytes read: 10
Message: Hello
Test PeekNamedPipe #3.
 - Number of bytes in pipe: 0

Done with client.
Done with server.
```

Comment: Do you remember to change the direction of the data you write as well? So you write to the client handle and read from the server handle?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - Thank you. I was not aware of this requirement about the direction of the data flow. I would be happy if you could point out that information in the documentation if it exist. The only criteria I was able to find in this regard is that the Handle given to the function must have read access.

Comment: Generally pipes are unidirectional, data flows only in one direction. Even for a duplex pipe the data written to one end of the pipe can only be read by the other. I don't have a reference about it, it just seemed natural to me to assume this knowing the nature of pipes as inherently unidirectional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation for PeekNamedPipe,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365779(v=vs.85).aspx) right at the top of the remarks:

> The PeekNamedPipe function is similar to the ReadFile function

You can't use ReadFile to read data you've sent to the other end of the pipe, so you can't use PeekNamedPipe to get information about the data you've sent to the other end of the pipe either.

If you want to know how much of the outgoing data the process at the other end of the pipe has read, you'll need to build some sort of feedback into your data protocol.